# issue with required parameter

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, positional-parameter

Create a new function named defaults with two parameters:

my_optional which has a default value of True
my_required which is a required param and has no default value
Return the following logical comparison:

my_optional is my_required
Expected Output

> > > defaults(True)
> > > True

> > > defaults(True, False)
> > > False

> > > defaults(False, False)
> > > True

def defaults(my_optional, my_required)
my_optional = True
return my_optional is my_required

## i received the error *defaults is missing positional argument: my_required

Comment: You have a function with two positional arguments, so when calling the function both of them need to be provided in the call. If you want to assign a default value to an argument, use a keyword argument with a default value, e.g.: `def defaults(my_required, my_optional=True)`.

Comment: Please see [How do I format my code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Also Stack Overflow's [markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page.